# A utility for auto-formatting .bib files?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

I have some `.bib` files whose formatting is kind of messy: spacing, upper/lowercase use, order within and among entries... ugh. Is there a simple command-line utility which could arrange it neatly for me in a uniform format?

Comment: biber can do it.

Comment: Also Emacs can do it.

Comment: @egreg: I said utility, not a self-contained operation system... :-)

Comment: @egreg an answer?

Comment: @egreg: You don't have to wait that I have time to expand a comment. I really don't mind if someone adds an answer based one of my comments. Btw: Since biber 2.9. you can use hyphens instead of underlines in the options. So `output-align` etc works too.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/formatting-bibtex-entries-using-auctex

Comment: [JabRef](http://jabref.sf.net) will normalize files when saving, i.e. align braces, use title case for all field keys, use 2 spaces for indentation... But unfortunately, JabRef will also add some new fields, like owner.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Option 1: With **Emacs** (in BibTeX mode), placing the cursor at the beginning of an entry and pressing `C-v C-Q` does `bibtex-fill-entry`, that can be customized in various ways.

Option 2: **Biber** has reformatting capabilities:

```
biber --tool --output_align --output_indent=2 --output_fieldcase=lower <filename>.bib
```

will produce `<filename>_bibertool.bib` with similar effects; I've shown some of the possible options. Biber is not limited to reformatting; fields can be removed and other changes are possible, see the manual.

Comment: Is biber available with all common distros? Is it part of a package?

Comment: @einpoklum It has been for some years, you need to issue that command from the command line.

Comment: It's not installed by default with MiKTeX 2.9; but it does come as [a package](http://miktex.org/packages/miktex-biber-bin).

Comment: In emacs, there is the menu item `BibTeX-Edit > Operating on Buffer or Region > Reformat Entries` which will deal more than one entry at a time.

Comment: biber works for me. Although I [don't like it's default alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243402/control-bibers-bibliography-entry-field-name-lengrh).

Answer (score 4):

There are some BibTex utilities on CTAN:
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils
The following two sound like they will do exactly what you asked for:

- bibtool: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool
- bibclean: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibclean

Comment: I'm having trouble getting those working as part of TexLive. Link?

Comment: I don't know if these tools are included in the Texlive and/or MikTex distribution. What operating systems are you on? On Ubuntu installation is as easy as `sudo apt-get install bibtool`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180840/seeking-bibtool-for-windows-binary

Comment: Windows. But I will say biber, which is included with TeXLive, now works-for-me, so I don't think I'll dig into this too deeply.