# How can I make biber output uniform field name lengths for all entries?

Tags: biber

When I run biber, with options

```
 biber --tool --output_align --output_indent=2 --output_fieldcase=lower
```

I get:

```
@inproceedings{foo,
  author    = {One, Some},
  booktitle = {International Conference on bar},
  title     = {How to foo while barring},
}

@misc{baz,
  note         = {Some note},
  organization = {The baz company},
  title        = {Baz title},
}
```

The thing is, I want all entries to have their '=' placed on the same column of the output file. In other words, I want biber to use the maximum field name length to align all entries, not just the maximum-within-the-bib-entry.

Can I make it do that?

Comment: A regular expression can be used on the output to shift `=` symbols to the right by 1 when they're not far enough into the line; and if it is applied repeatedly, n-1 times, then all fields will be aligned with the `=` on column n at least. If n is the rightmost position of a `=`, this will suffice. An awk script can probably do this more simply with counting.